# limit calculation step by step

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I calculate such limit with *Mathematica*:

```
Limit[(Log[u] (Log[1 + (2 u)/(I - 2 t)] - Log[1 - (2 u)/(I + 2 t)]) + 
      PolyLog[2, (2 u)/(-I + 2 t)] - PolyLog[2, (2 u)/(I + 2 t)]), 
      u -> ∞]
```

> ```
>  1/2 (-Log[2/(I - 2 t)]^2 + Log[-(2/(I + 2 t))]^2).
> ```

I would like to know the calculation steps. *Wolfram Alpha* gives no answer.

Comment: Have you tried `Trace`?

Comment: Yes. It wasn't helpful.

Comment: Generally Mathematica doesn't provide intermediate steps. You're probably out of luck here.

Comment: Limit will attempt to form a series at infinity. In some cases it can then deduce limiting behavior. In more extreme cases it may need to resort to an exp-log (hierarchical) series.